# Why variable n isn't visible in second listener in Java?

Tags: java, variables, listener, visible

I don't know why variable n isn't visible in second listener. All is in the question. Below I adding a code. This is only a part of all source code.

```
ActionListener lis5 = new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        String a = t1.getText();
        int n = Integer.parseInt(a);
    } 
};
b1.addActionListener(lis5);

ActionListener lis6 = new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        int [] tab = new int[n];
        for (int i=0;i<n;i++) {
            tab[i] = in.nextInt();
        }
    } 
};
b2.addActionListener(lis6);
```

Comment: The scope of a variable is limited to the `{` and `}` it is in side.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use a variable of one method in another method?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9351955/how-to-use-a-variable-of-one-method-in-another-method)

Answer (score 1):

Because n is in the scope of an [anonymous interface](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html).

Accessing Local Variables of the Enclosing Scope, and Declaring and Accessing Members of the Anonymous Class

> Like local classes, anonymous classes can capture variables; they have
>   the same access to local variables of the enclosing scope:
>
> An anonymous class has access to the members of its enclosing class.
>
> An anonymous class cannot access local variables in its enclosing
>   scope that are not declared as final or effectively final.
>
> Like a nested class, a declaration of a type (such as a variable) in
>   an anonymous class shadows any other declarations in the enclosing
>   scope that have the same name. See Shadowing for more information.
>
> Anonymous classes also have the same restrictions as local classes
>   with respect to their members:
>
> You cannot declare static initializers or member interfaces in an
>   anonymous class.
>
> An anonymous class can have static members provided that they are
>   constant variables.

Answer (score 1):

`n` is declared in the scope of the first `actionPerformed`. It will "disappear" as soon as the method ends.

Declare it outside of the methods

```
int n = 0;

ActionListener lis5 = new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        String a = t1.getText();
        n = Integer.parseInt(a)
    } 
};
b1.addActionListener(lis5); 

int[] tab;

ActionListener lis6 = new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        tab = new int[n];
        for(int i = 0 ; i < n ; i++) {
            tab[i] = in.nextInt();
        }
    } 
};
b2.addActionListener(lis6);
```

Same goes for the deceleration of `tab` array.

Comment: @belusa16 I added this to my answer.

Comment: thanks, but can you correct my code, because I still don't know what I can do it?

Comment: @belusa16 I did. I posted the solution in my answer.

Comment: b1 and b2 is a Button and i want that when i hit the b1 a program get value from t1(TextField) ; when i hit b2 in second listener value from n(first listener) will be processed in b2 listaner, can you change it again ;)

Comment: @belusa16 I edited my answer. Declare `n` outside the methods and initialize it to 0 to prevent errors in case you press on `b2` button first.

Comment: @Guy you can't use non-final variables from the enclosing scope in anonymous classes.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to be able to update the variable in one action listener, and then use it in another action listener, you need a reference to a mutable value type to share between the two.

You can simply use `int[1]`, but I prefer to use `AtomicInteger`, since it is more clear that there is exactly one integer value being shared then:

```
final AtomicInteger n = new AtomicInteger();
ActionListener lis5 = new ActionListener(){
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        String a = t1.getText();
        n.set(Integer.parseInt(a));
    } 
};
b1.addActionListener(lis5); 

ActionListener lis6 = new ActionListener(){
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        int nn = n.get();
        int [] tab = new int[nn];
        for(int i=0;i<nn;i++){
            tab[i] = in.nextInt();
        }
    } 
};
b2.addActionListener(lis6);
```

Comment: ok that's clear thanks; I have a second question. I want write program who in t1(TextField) enter how many numbers user want enter and confirm by b1(Button). In t2(TextField) user give a first value and enter it by b2, in next time user give a second value and again enter it by b2. It happens so much times as high is n(from first listener).  How I must change code from Andy Turner that program to do it, but now when i give to t2 first value and hit the button then b2 is still pressed..

Comment: Your additional question is very unclear (particularly with the formatting available in comments), and it's not especially good form to add on rider question like this. I suggest you ask it as a separate question.