# is there any way to get access to a function local variables in java

Tags: java

Suppose I have a `function` in Java.

```
public function goodname(int a){
    int b=8;
}
```

Is there any way to access variable `b` without getter and setter?
I was asked this question in an interview. My answer was NO but he insisted that there is a way i am wondering how can i do this?

Comment: Hopefully in the interview the code would at least compile?

Comment: Java doesn't have functions. Only methods.

Comment: Quoting the dup question: *1) Any variable declared in a method is only visible in that method. (method-local). The programmer has no choice in that.*

Comment: @GhostCat: Other possible dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9351955/how-to-use-a-variable-of-one-method-in-another-method

Comment: I think you mean `javascript` rather than `java`. These are two [completely different languages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/245062/whats-the-difference-between-javascript-and-java), but often confused. I suggested an edit to your question.

Comment: @chade_ You can't declare integers in JavaScript.

Comment: @Ivar Thanks. I updated the dup request. Now I almost hope some more downvotes come in so we can delete this thing here.

Answer (score 3):

No, `b` is entirely private to the `goodname` method. It cannot be accessed by code outside `goodname` unless it's exposed in some way by code within it.

Answer (score 0):

No, this `b` only exists while `goodname` is being executed. You can't access it from outside.

Answer (score -1):

There is no way to access the inner variable. You can't access it from outside. Unless you make it like below

```
public int b=8;

public function goodname(int a){
//b = 8;
}
```

Comment: "Make it generic" ... so the answer that uses the "most wrong" language gets the accept. You didn't even take the time to fix the wrong syntax.