# How pass value from a method to another in a servlet

Tags: java, servlets

```
private void ajouterActeurFilm(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
    String nom= request.getParameter("acteurRecherche");
    ArrayList<Celebrite> listeActeurs= dao.RechercherActeur(nom);
    RequestDispatcher dispatcher
            = request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/AjouterActeurFilm.jsp");
    dispatcher.forward(request, response);
}

private void ajouterActeur(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
    String id=request.getParameter("idMedia");
     RequestDispatcher dispatcher
            = request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/AjouterActeurFilm.jsp");
    dispatcher.forward(request, response);
}
```

I would like to know if is possible to pass the value `id` from the method `ajouterActeur` to `ajouterActeurFilm`.

Comment: i want to pass this value "String id=request.getParameter("idMedia"); " to the method ajouterActeurFilm(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use a variable of one method in another method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9351955/how-to-use-a-variable-of-one-method-in-another-method)

Comment: Please consider revising the code sample you posted in this question. As it currently stands, its formatting and scope make it hard for us to help you; here is a [great resource](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to get you started on that. -1, don't take it the wrong way. A down vote is how we indicate a content problem around here; improve your formatting and code sample and I (or someone will) gladly revert it. Good luck with your code!

Answer (score 0):

**You can set the value like:**

```
private void ajouterActeur(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
        String id = request.getParameter("idMedia");  
        request.setAttribute("id",id);          
        RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/AjouterActeurFilm.jsp");
        dispatcher.forward(request, response);
    }
```

**And you can get the value as:**

```
private void ajouterActeurFilm(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
        String nom = request.getParameter("acteurRecherche");
        ArrayList<Celebrite> listeActeurs = dao.RechercherActeur(nom);
        String id = (String) request.getAttribute("id");
        RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/AjouterActeurFilm.jsp");
        dispatcher.forward(request, response);
    }
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.