# How do I use variables in one method into another method?

Tags: java, variables, methods, static-methods

So I was wondering if someone could show me how I can call/reference a variable from one method into another method. For example,

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    System.out.println("Welcome to the game of sticks!");
    playerNames();
    coinToss();
}

public static void playerNames()
{
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println();

    System.out.print("Enter player 1's name: ");
    String p1 = input.nextLine();

    System.out.print("Enter player 2's name: ");
    String p2 = input.nextLine();

    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("Welcome, " + p1 + " and " + p2 + ".");
}

public static void coinToss()
{
    System.out.println("A coin toss will decide who goes first:");
    System.out.println();
    Random rand = new Random();
    int result = rand.nextInt(2);
    result = rand.nextInt(2);
    if(result == 0)
    {
        System.out.println(p1 + " goes first!");
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println(p2 + " goes first!");
    }           
}
```

I want to use p1 and p2 from playerNames() inside of coinToss() so I can simply announce who goes first, but I just can't figure out how to call the variables.

My question is not really different compared to others, however I was unable to understand the answers others were given. Once I posted this I got the answer from a bunch of kind people :)

Comment: Have you learned about method parameters yet?

Comment: In many cases you can make instance variables, which go outside of the method, and can then be accessed by all methods.  With static methods like you have here you'll have to use static variables though.

Comment: @Andreas Yes, however I don't think I would need it for this case as I will have everything running on its own when I call the methods in the static void main.

Comment: @markspace Would you mind showing me what that would look like? I am a little confused on how it would work because the answers I am looking for (the names) are inside of the method, and the names can vary all the time. I don't want them to be set to a specific name.

Comment: I'd really like to see you attempt that code yourself.  It's very simple and working it out will help you understand how to code better.  Basic info on syntax is here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html

Comment: @markspace wow, thank you so much haha. I figured it out in less than two minutes! I feel really happy right now haha :D Is there a way for me to show how I did it? Still new to answering and asking questions.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use a variable of one method in another method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9351955/how-to-use-a-variable-of-one-method-in-another-method)

Comment: @geisterfurz007 It might be, but I already looked at that one and a whole bunch of others before asking my question. I couldn't seem to understand it from those ones.

Comment: `Is there a way for me to show how I did it?` You could answer your own question.  That's permitted here and I think you even get a little badge for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you are new to Java, because it seems you aren't familiar with the concept of *fields* (i.e. you can put variables *outside* methods).

```
public class YourClass {
    static String p1;
    static String p2;

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        System.out.println("Welcome to the game of sticks!");
        playerNames();
        coinToss();
    }

    public static void playerNames()
    {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println();

        System.out.print("Enter player 1's name: ");
        p1 = input.nextLine();

        System.out.print("Enter player 2's name: ");
        p2 = input.nextLine();

        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Welcome, " + p1 + " and " + p2 + ".");
    }

    public static void coinToss()
    {
        System.out.println("A coin toss will decide who goes first:");
        System.out.println();
        Random rand = new Random();
        int result = rand.nextInt(2);
        result = rand.nextInt(2);
        if(result == 0)
        {
            System.out.println(p1 + " goes first!");
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println(p2 + " goes first!");
        }           
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

what you are searching for is called instance variables, check this out.
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_variable_types.htm

Answer (score 0):

All I had to do was create the instance/static variables outside! Like this:

```
static String name1;
static String name2;
```

It was very easy. Thanks everyone for your help!