# How to get TextField value from another class or method

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jtextfield

I don't know how JTextField works. I'm trying a lots.
My question is: **How to get TextField value from another class or method?**

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class MuGUI extends JPanel {
    public MyGui() {
        JTextField betText = new JTextField("");    
    }

    public void method2() {
        // error this line, cant find betText
        String value = betText.getText();
    }
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to the stackoverflow. You really should read [How to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). And then reformat your question.

Comment: You can't use a variable of a method in another method

Comment: @B.M how can i solve this ?

Comment: [Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/85421)

Comment: @eXpect this may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9351955/how-to-use-a-variable-of-one-method-in-another-method

Comment: are you sure the variable is from "Main class"? And what is the "inner class" in posted IMAGE? (wondering when the first video to show errors will be posted feeling *so old* using just copy&paste for code or text)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can declare your JTextField globally and then you initialize it inside your constructor. Now you have access to your variable in your methods too.

```
public class MyGUI extends JPanel
{
  private JTextField betText;

  public MyGUI(){
     //other operations
     betText = new JTextField("");
  }

  public void test(){
     String a = betText.getText();
  }
 }
```

Comment: `public class MyGUI extends JPanel` That's where this answer (& presumably the OP) starts to go wrong. Prefer composition over inheritance and the stated problem will be resolved.

Comment: *"I have just.."* ..perpetuated the problem. A well deserved down-vote that is. Kudos!